# How to type hint a function with an alias

Tags: python, type-hinting

I'd like to type hint a number of functions with a given alias but I can't see an obvious clean way of doing this. For example, with

```py
Foo = Callable[[int], str]


def foo1(x: int) -> str:
    ...


def foo2(x: int) -> str:
    ...
```

it's pretty easy to see these are both `Foo`s, but I have functions with much more complicated signatures, and inspecting them by eye is tiresome and error prone.

I'm looking for something like this idris code

```
Foo : Type
Foo = Int -> String

foo1 : Foo
foo1 x = ?rhs

foo2 : Foo
foo2 x = ?rhs
```

Here it's obvious what's a `Foo`, and if I have functions which are `Int -> String` but not intentionally `Foo`s, that's clear.

One way is

```py
Foo = Callable[[int], str]


def _foo1(x: int) -> str:
    ...

foo1 : Foo = _foo1
```

but I'd like to find something that works more naturally with docs and doesn't require (a kind of) duplication.

Comment: You mean that basically, you want to typehint a function `def`enition with `Foo` directly? I don't think you can do that. You could do `f: Foo = lambda x: "some string"`, but that's quite limited and breaks PEP8 guidelines.

Comment: @Carcigenicate well that'd be perfect, yes, but I'm not looking to change python's syntax. I'm just looking for a workaround that's not going to require more workarounds as I progress

Answer (score 0):

> I have functions with much more complicated signatures, and inspecting them by eye is tiresome and error prone.

> if I have functions which are `int -> str` but not intentionally `Foo`s, that's clear.

Considering these two points, it's clear that this is intended to help humans, not type checkers.
Keeping that in mind, a solution, that looks nice in PyCharm (at least showing the type alias on screen, albeit as a decorator argument) and doesn't trigger WPS linter, is the following:

```py
# turns a two-argument function
# that accepts our function as *second* argument
# and returns it without any changes at runtime
# into a no-runtime-overhead decorator factory
annotate = partial(partial, cast)  # from typing import cast

Foo = Callable[[int], str]

@annotate(Foo)
def foo1(x: int) -> str:
    ...

@annotate(Foo)
def foo2(x: int) -> str:
    ...
```

The `@annotate(Foo)` line is shown in PyCharm tooltip shown on hovering over `foo1` and `foo2` functions. And even the docstring isn't lost, if present!

Sadly, the following...

```py
@annotate(Foo)
def foo(x):
    ...
```

...doesn't tell PyCharm the types of `foo`'s return value and `x` argument, but this workaround is neither intended nor expected to do that.

P.S. Not sure if `annotate` is the best name for this decorator, but this is clearly an attempt to annotate a function variable, so...
I considered `mark_as` or `with_alias`, but those aren't as likely to prompt (or help with by directing) additional research by someone learning Python by reading others' code.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of `annotate`